# Date bug? receiving error only on certain dates

Tags: python, datetime, strftime

The following code gets the start of the week of a date argument:

```
weekstart = datetime.datetime.strptime(sys.argv[1], '%m/%d/%Y')

if weekstart.strftime('%A') != 'Sunday':
    print "Start date should be a Sunday"
    while weekstart.strftime('%A') != 'Sunday':
        #weekstart = weekstart - datetime.timedelta(a)
        a=a+1
    print "Using %s as start date instead" %weekstart.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

I receive the following error only when the date entered is 7/10/2012, 7/11/2012, 7/12/2012, or 7/13/2012:

```
while weekstart.strftime('%A') != 'Sunday':

ValueError: year=1899 is before 1900; the datetime strftime() methods require year >= 1900
```

What is wrong with this?

Comment: Have you checked the `weekstart` variable right after you construct it? I.e. print it out right after the call to `strptime`.

Comment: Yes i inserted print weekstart.strftime() for %d %m %y, and %A. the output are all correct. but the code this errors on the while "weekstart.strftime('%A') != 'Sunday': "line

Comment: what does the variable `a` refer to in your example snippet?

Comment: It is for my iteration of datetime.timedelta() to go back one day at a time

Comment: @user1519887 - no, it does not go back **one** day at a time. You are incrementing `a` at a time. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a bug in your concept. You are incorrectly incrementing `a` and decreasing `weekstart` by that `a`. So it does not go day by day, but by 1, 2, 3, 4,… days.

- `7/10/2012` is Tuesday. Substract 1 day…
- `7/9/2012` is Monday. Substract 2 days…
- `7/7/2012` is Saturday. Substract 3 days…
- `7/4/2012` is Wednesday. Substract 4 days…
- `6/30/2012` is Saturday. Substract 5 days…
- `6/25/2012` is Monday. Substract 6 days…
- `6/19/2012` is Tuesday. Substract 7 days, i.e. one week and the loop goes on faster and faster until the year 1899 when it breaks.

It means that if your first day is Tuesday, it will never reach Sunday this way.

It works for 7/11/2012 (and any Wednesday), it breaks for 7/12/2012 (and any Thursday), it breaks for 7/13/2012 (and any Friday), it works for 7/14/2012 (and any Saturday) and it works for 7/16/2012 (and any Monday) and of course it stops immediately for any Sunday.

But it is not what you want.

If you want to get the previous (or today's) Sunday for any day without loops, just use this:

```
weekstart = weekstart - datetime.timedelta((weekstart.weekday() - 6) % 7)
```

Or, if you want to avoid mathematics and use libraries ([dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil/)):

```
from dateutil import relativedelta

weekstart = weekstart + relativedelta.relativedelta(weekday=relativedelta.SU(-1))
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I changed %A to weekday() instead. However, it still doesn't work for the said bugging dates

Comment: ah yes i removed that in my code (i commented it to pinpoint where the error is coming from) but not in the one i pasted sorry. Nonetheless, the error is still in the `while weekstart.strftime('%A') != 'Sunday':`

Comment: Thanks @eumiro! I'm using your code now. But still I'm curious why that happens, is that a bug?

Comment: @user1519887 - ok, there goes the explanation of the bug in your code.